# openMp: severe perfomance loss when calling shared references of dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, optimization, openmp

I am writing a cfd simulation and want to parallelise my ~10^5 loop (lattice size), which is part of a member function. The implementation of the openMp code is straight forward: I read entries of shared arrays, do calculations with thread-private quantities and finally write in a shared array again. In every array I only access the array element of the loop number, so I don't expect a race condition and I don't see any reason to flush. Testing the speedup of the code(the parallel part), I find that all but one cpu run at only ~70%. 
Has anybody an idea how to improve this?

```
void class::funcPar(bool parallel){
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int one, two, three;
    double four, five;

    #pragma omp for
    for(int b=0; b<lenAr; b++){
        one = A[b]+B[b];
        C[b] = one;
        one += D[b];
        E[b] = one;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It looks like a memory bound problem. When run on a single thread, do you also see the same 70%? Note that things like vectorization can also be screwed up when introducing OMP. Also, can you add some timings to give a general idea of runtimes?

Comment: no, on a single thread I have 100% for the whole time.

Comment: I got only 1/3 speed up using 4 cores. From there I started using the load average of htop to observe to what extend my parallel section is distributed (obviously not optimal). The Code above is not the real code i am running but shows the only operations that I run in my simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several points, then test code, then discussion:

1. 10^5 isn't that much if each item is an `int`. The incurred overhead of launching multiple threads *might* be greater than the benefits.
2. Compiler optimizations can get messed with when using OMP.
3. When dealing with few operations per set of memory, loops can be memory bound (i.e. the CPU spends time waiting for requested memory to be delivered)

As promised, here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <Eigen/Core>


Eigen::VectorXi A;
Eigen::VectorXi B;
Eigen::VectorXi D;
Eigen::VectorXi C;
Eigen::VectorXi E;
int size;

void regular()
{
    //#pragma omp parallel
    {
        int one;
//      #pragma omp for
        for(int b=0; b<size; b++){
            one = A[b]+B[b];
            C[b] = one;
            one += D[b];
            E[b] = one;
        }
    }
}

void parallel()
{
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        int one;
        #pragma omp for
        for(int b=0; b<size; b++){
            one = A[b]+B[b];
            C[b] = one;
            one += D[b];
            E[b] = one;
        }
    }
}

void vectorized()
{
    C = A+B;
    E = C+D;
}

void both()
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        int vals = size / nthreads;
        int startInd = tid * vals;
        if(tid == nthreads - 1)
            vals += size - nthreads * vals;
        auto am = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXi>(A.data() + startInd, vals);
        auto bm = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXi>(B.data() + startInd, vals);
        auto cm = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXi>(C.data() + startInd, vals);
        auto dm = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXi>(D.data() + startInd, vals);
        auto em = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXi>(E.data() + startInd, vals);
        cm = am+bm;
        em = cm+dm;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    size = 100000;
    int iterations = 10;
    if(argc > 1)
        size = atoi(argv[1]);
    if(argc > 2)
        iterations = atoi(argv[2]);
    std::cout << "Size: " << size << "\n";
    A = Eigen::VectorXi::Random(size);
    B = Eigen::VectorXi::Random(size);
    D = Eigen::VectorXi::Random(size);
    C = Eigen::VectorXi::Zero(size);
    E = Eigen::VectorXi::Zero(size);

    auto startReg = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        regular();
    auto endReg = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cerr << C.sum() - E.sum() << "\n";

    auto startPar = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        parallel();
    auto endPar = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cerr << C.sum() - E.sum() << "\n";

    auto startVec = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        vectorized();
    auto endVec = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cerr << C.sum() - E.sum() << "\n";

    auto startPVc = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        both();
    auto endPVc = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cerr << C.sum() - E.sum() << "\n";

    std::cout << "Timings:\n";
    std::cout << "Regular:    " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(endReg - startReg).count() / iterations << "\n";
    std::cout << "Parallel:   " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(endPar - startPar).count() / iterations << "\n";
    std::cout << "Vectorized: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(endVec - startVec).count() / iterations << "\n";
    std::cout << "Both      : " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(endPVc - startPVc).count() / iterations << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I used [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) as a vector library to help prove a point re:optimizations, which I'll reach soon. Code was compiled in four different optimization modes:

> g++ -fopenmp -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -pthread     -I C:\usr\include source.cpp -o   a.exe
>
> g++ -fopenmp -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -pthread -O1 -I C:\usr\include source.cpp -o aO1.exe
>
> g++ -fopenmp -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -pthread -O2 -I C:\usr\include source.cpp -o aO2.exe
>
> g++ -fopenmp -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -pthread -O3 -I C:\usr\include source.cpp -o aO3.exe

using g++ (x86_64-posix-sjlj, built by strawberryperl.com project) 4.8.3 under Windows.

### Discussion

We'll start by looking at 10^5 vs 10^6 elements, averaged 100 times without optimizations.

a 10^5 (without optimizations):

```
Timings:
Regular:    9300
Parallel:   2620
Vectorized: 2170
Both      : 910
```

a 10^6 (without optimizations):

```
Timings:
Regular:    93535
Parallel:   27191
Vectorized: 21831
Both      : 8600
```

Vectorization (SIMD) trumps OMP in terms of speedup. Combined, we get even better times.

Moving to -O1:

10^5:

```
Timings:
Regular:    780
Parallel:   300
Vectorized: 80
Both      : 80
```

10^6:

```
Timings:
Regular:    7340
Parallel:   2220
Vectorized: 1830
Both      : 1670
```

Same as without optimizations except that timings are much better.

Skipping ahead to -O3:

10^5:

```
Timings:
Regular:    380
Parallel:   130
Vectorized: 80
Both      : 70
```

10^6:

```
Timings:
Regular:    3080
Parallel:   1750
Vectorized: 1810
Both      : 1680
```

For 10^5, optimizations still trump. However, 10^6 gives faster timings for OMP loops than the vectorization.

In all the tests, we got about a x2-x4 speedup for OMP.

Note: I originally ran the tests when I had another low priority process using all the cores. For some reason, this affected *mainly* the parallel tests, and not the others. Make sure you time things correctly.

### Conclusion

Your minimal code example does not behave as claimed. Issues such as memory access patterns can arise with more complex data. Add enough detail to accurately reproduce your problem ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) to get better help.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. As to your first remark: my example given is rather bad: the program is a lot bigger than that and mostly deals with doubles. (more of that later). As to the compiler optimisation: That is a very interesting point! I was hoping to improve performance by the number of threads after optimisation. were you using four cores? I believe your third point is the crucial one: I have about 80 dynamic arrays (most of them double) of length lenAr. Apart from minor calculations on private variables, I only read and write in these

Comment: arrays, taking care not to access same references in different threads. Admittedly, my example program does not show this. But after a lot of research I found that not only concurrent access to the same reference causes a race condition but also concurrent access to the same cache line! I have not thought of this and don't find a solution, as references to dynamic arrays must not be shared and copying is out of question.

Comment: @FrankUnderwood, concurrent access to the same cache line is called [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing). Race conditions and false sharing are two of the most common problems in parallelization.

Comment: €Z Boson, I believe that is exactly, what I was missing! There's a good reference on that Wikipedia link, that describes the problem and the solution in detail. Thanks.

Comment: _"For some reason, this affected mainly the parallel tests, and not the others."_ The reason is that because of the implicit barrier at the end of the parallel region, if time-sharing or OS jitter slows down one of the threads, it slows down the entire parallel region as the other threads have to wait for the delayed one to finish its work. Adding the `schedule(dynamic,chunk)` clause with appropriately sized `chunk` provides a remedy in such cases.

Comment: €Avi Ginsburg, Why did you choose to go for the Eigen library? I tried them with my improved example code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30977618/openmp-optimisation-of-dynamic-array-access?noredirect=1#comment49992965_30977618 and it was slower than using normal dynamic arrays. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Tom What OS, compiler, flags, optimizations are you using? Those make all the difference.

Comment: @Avi Ginsburg, I'm running debian in virtual box, compile with g++ and use only -Wall -Wuninitialized, -fopenmp, -c. I found, that the eigen library gets enormously faster using compiler optimizations but not as fast as usual dynamic arrays. Is that all right?

Comment: @Tom In addition to `-O3` you can/should add `-DNDEBUG`. This will disable runtime assertions which can slow down performance.